# How to convert unicoded web scraped data in to english language

Tags: r, web-scraping, unicode

I have scraped the data from the web and its output is in unicode as shown in comment

<U+0907><U+0928><U+094D><U+0938><U+093E><U+0907><U+0915><U+094D><U+0932><U+094B><U+092A><U+0940><U+0921><U+093F><U+092F><U+093E> <U+092C><U+094D><U+0930><U+093F><U+091F><U+0948><U+0928><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>

now how to translate this data into english using R

<U+0907><U+0928><U+094D><U+0938><U+093E><U+0907><U+0915><U+094D><U+0932><U+094B><U+092A><U+0940><U+0921><U+093F><U+092F><U+093E> <U+092C><U+094D><U+0930><U+093F><U+091F><U+0948><U+0928><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>

Comment: <U+0907><U+0928><U+094D><U+0938><U+093E><U+0907><U+0915><U+094D><U+0932><U+094B><U+092A><U+0940><U+0921><U+093F><U+092F><U+093E> <U+092C><U+094D><U+0930><U+093F><U+091F><U+0948><U+0928><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>

Comment: please `dput` your data so that people can reproduce it

Comment: structure(list(ID = 7357, Title = structure(1L, .Label = "<U+0905><U+092C> <U+0928><U+0939><U+0940><U+0902> <U+091B><U+092A><U+0947><U+0917><U+0940> <U+0907><U+0928><U+094D><U+0938><U+093E><U+0907><U+0915><U+094D><U+0932><U+094B><U+092A><U+0940><U+0921><U+093F><U+092F><U+093E> <U+092C><U+094D><U+0930><U+093F><U+091F><U+0948><U+0928><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>", class = "factor"),

Comment: You can unescape unicode like this: `myList$Title %>% stri_replace_all_regex("<U\\+(....)>", "\\\\u$1") %>% stri_unescape_unicode()`. It will give "अब नहीं छपेगी इन्साइक्लोपीडिया ब्रिटैनिका" in my environment, but you probably have a lot of trouble if you are using windows (which I assume you are).

Answer (score 0):

your dput is corrupted. I am still trying to reproduce your data. And following it up with a solution.

```
library(stringi)
library(stringr)

a <- structure(list(ID = 7357, Title = structure(1L, .Label = "<U+0905><U+092C> <U+0928><U+0939><U+0940><U+0902> <U+091B><U+092A><U+0947><U+0917><U+0940> <U+0907><U+0928><U+094D><U+0938><U+093E><U+0907><\
U+0915><U+094D><U+0932><U+094B><U+092A><U+0940><U+0921><U+093F><U+092F><U+093E> <U+092C><U+094D><U+0930><U+093F><U+091F><U+0948><U+0928><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>", class = "factor")))
titles <- as.character(a$Title)
titles_in_unicode <- lapply(
    unlist(strsplit(titles,' ')),
    FUN = function(words) {
        paste(stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("U+",
                                   "\\u",
                                   unlist(str_extract_all(words,
                                                          "U\\+([0-9]?)+([A-Z]?)+")),
                                   fixed=TRUE)),collapse='')
    }
)
```

Output

```
!> titles_in_unicode
 [[1]]
 [1] "अब"

 [[2]]
 [1] "नहीं"

 [[3]]
 [1] "छपेगी"

 [[4]]
 [1] "इन्साइक्लोपीडिया"

 [[5]]
 [1] "ब्रिटैनिका"
```